# PROGRAM to find least common entry in array

Tags: java, arrays

I was writing the code for the least occurring element in the array and for some reason my logic goes wrong and the compiler just prints either the first or the second element in the array? anyone know what's wrong?

```
package javaapplication10;
import java.util.*;

public class JavaApplication10 {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        int  m =1000;
        int count = 0;
        int store = 0;
        int c = 0;
        Scanner scan = new Scanner(System.in);
        int[] a = new int[20] ;
        int n;
        System.out.print("Enter no of elements");
        n = scan.nextInt();
        for(int i =0; i<n;i++) {
            a[i] = scan.nextInt();
        }
        for(int i =0; i <n ; i++) {  
            c = a[i] ; 
            for(int j =0; j <n ; j++) { 
                if(a[j] ==c) {
                    count++ ;
                }
                if(j == (n-1)) {
                    if(count<m ) {
                    store = a[i];
                    m = count;
                   }
                }
                count = 0;
            }
       }
       System.out.print(store);
    }
}
```

Comment: If your current output does not match your desired output, and you don't know why, then it's time to start debugging. If you're not sure how to go about doing this, then please have a look at: [How to Debug Small Programs](http://ericlippert.com/2014/03/05/how-to-debug-small-programs/). It won't solve your direct problem, but it will give you steps that you can follow that should help you solve it yourself, or even if that is not successful, then at least help you to better isolate your problem so that your question can be more focused and easier to answer.

Comment: You're asking users to input the number of elements, but your `a` int array is given size 20. That's asking for an ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException. Also, you should try to give your variables more descriptive names. Single character variables are always jarring, except in the cases of `i` and `j`

Comment: I commend you on your effort to do this with logic but it might make things easier if you used a data structure to hold each unique element and its count.

Comment: But arrays are datastructures aren't they? If not then then what type of datastructures?

Answer (score 1):

A better solution is to do sorting. We first sort the array, then linearly traverse the array.

```
static int leastFrequent(int arr[], int n)
// n is length of array
    {

        // Sort the array
        Arrays.sort(arr);

        // find the min frequency using 
        // linear traversal
        int min_count = n+1, res = -1;
        int curr_count = 1;

        for (int i = 1; i < n; i++) {
            if (arr[i] == arr[i - 1])
                curr_count++;
            else {
                if (curr_count < min_count) {
                    min_count = curr_count;
                    res = arr[i - 1];
                }

                curr_count = 1;
            }
        }

        // If last element is least frequent
        if (curr_count < min_count)
        {
            min_count = curr_count;
            res = arr[n - 1];
        }

        return res;
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

I guess you are trying to implement the following logic

1. Find the count of each element in the array
2. If you find an element with lower count - store the element
3. Repeat for each element in the array - to find the lowest element.

You should have rest the `count` at the end of the inner loop as,

```
package javaapplication10;
import java.util.*;

public class JavaApplication10 {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        int  m =1000;
        int count = 0;
        int store = 0;
        int c = 0;
        Scanner scan = new Scanner(System.in);
        int[] a = new int[20] ;
        int n;
        System.out.print("Enter no of elements");
        n = scan.nextInt();
        for(int i =0; i<n;i++) {
            a[i] = scan.nextInt();
        }
        for(int i =0; i <n ; i++) {  
            c = a[i] ; 
            for(int j =0; j <n ; j++) { 
                if(a[j] ==c) {
                    count++ ;
                }
                if(j == (n-1)) {
                    if(count<m ) {
                    store = a[i];
                    m = count;
                   }
                }
            }
         count = 0;
       }
       System.out.print(store);
    }
}
```

Comment: Thanks for this! extremely useful!

Answer (score 0):

You have a single counter, so you'll lose this counting once you transition from one element to another.

You could hold an auxiliary map of counters and update it as you go, but frankly, using Java's streams will save you a lot of boilerplate code:

```
int leastOccuring = 
    Arrays.stream(a)
          .boxed()
          .collect(Collectors.groupingBy(Function.identity(), Collectors.counting())
          .entrySet()
          .stream()
          .min(Map.Entry.comparingByValue())
          .map(Map.Entry::geyKey)
          .get();
```

Answer (score 0):

This would be the correct code for your program.

```
import java.util.*;

public class LeastOccuringElementInArray {

    public static void main(String[] args) {

        int  m = 0;
        int count = 0;
        int store = 0;
        int c = 0;
       Scanner scan = new Scanner(System.in);
        int[] a = new int[20] ;
       int n;
       System.out.print("Enter no of elements");
       n = scan.nextInt();

       for(int i =0; i<n;i++)
       {
           a[i] = scan.nextInt();
       }
       for(int i =0; i <n ; i++)
        {  c = a[i] ; 
               for(int j =0; j <n ; j++)
                {
                       if(a[j] == c)
                       {
                           count++ ;

                       }
                       if(j == (n-1))
                       {
                            if(m!=0 && m > count)
                            {
                                  store = a[i];
                                  m = count;

                            }
                            else {
                                m = count;
                            }
                        }

             }

               count = 0;

    }
                System.out.print(store);
                scan.close();
    } 
}
```

Comment: Although there can be more than one least occurring element in your array, so make a **list** where you have used **store** and then keep adding the least occurring elements